# Why is my If statement accepting an incorrect String condition in PHP?

Tags: php, string, conditional-statements

I am very confused, because PHP accepts the below condition.

```
<?php
   $b = true;
   if($b == 'anything') 
      echo 'ok';
   else
      echo 'no';
?>
```

Well, PHP displays `ok`. I still don't understand how is it possible.

Maybe, you can clarify it for me.

Comment: PHP is a loose typed language so casting might occur when possible. Use strict comparisons `$b === 'hello' // false` whenever you can. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Setting `$b` to `true` and then assigning a value to `$b` are both conditions that fit 'truthiness'. If you need a strict comparison use `===`

Comment: [how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)

Comment: A non-empty string is seen as equivalent to `true` in loose comparisons in PHP, as simple as that.

Answer (score 5):

this should work for you

```
$b = true;
if($b === 'hello') 
    echo 'ok';
else
    echo 'no';
```

when using `==` php will only checks if values are equal, without comparing the values types, when first value is a bool, php will convert both sides to bool, converting any string but the empty string `''` and the string `'0'` will return `true`, that's why you have to use `===`

follow this [link](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php) to understand comparison in php

Comment: I would explain *why*.

Answer (score 1):

Php is not a strictly typed language so the value in the second half of the IF statement is considered a Truthy value. If you want to complare types as well use the "===" comparison. Take a look at the truthy table on this page. http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 1):

According to the PHP manual on comparison operators (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `==` checks for "equalness" whereas `===` checks for identity (which practically means it is of same TYPE and of same VALUE).

When comparing (for equalness) a `bool` and a `string`, the `string` gets casted to a `bool`. According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

```
When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
* the boolean FALSE itself
* the integer 0 (zero)
* the float 0.0 (zero)
* the empty string, and the string "0"
* an array with zero elements
```

so your string `'anything'` becomes `true`.